# How to prevent Windows Installer from running each time Access 2003 and 2007 start when there are installed on the same machine?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to prevent the Windows Installer from running every time Access 2003 and Access 2007 are started, when they are both installed on the same machine at the same time..?

Like many developers I need to run more than 1 version of MS Access.  I have just installed Access 2007.  If I open Access 2003 and then open Access 2007 I have to wait 3mins for the 'Configuring Microsoft Office Enterprise 2007..." dialog.  Then if I open Access 2003 again it takes another 30secs or so to configure that.

PLEASE NOTE: I am using shortcuts to open the files that include the full path to Access.  Eg to open Access 2007:

```
 "C:\program files\microsoft office 12\office12\msaccess.exe" "C:\test.accdb"
```

and for 2003:

```
 "C:\program files\microsoft office 11\office11\msaccess.exe" "C:\test.mdb"
```

Answer (score 3):

The fix to the problem is very simple as it turns out - 
simply run the following commands (by pressing the Windows Key+R or typing it into the Start/Run command box. 
 Use the line with Office\11.0 if you have Office 2003 installed and Office\12.0 if you have Office 2007 installed. 
 You can use both if you have both installed :

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1

reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options /v NoReReg /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

That is it.  Office 2007 might want to have one more spin round the block with it's configuration dialog box, but that should be it.

C: \Program Files>Common Files>microsoft shared>OFFICE12>Office Setup Controller>SETUP.exe change to SETUPold.exe

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Access.Application]

This key will cause the config screen to constantly cycle everytime you open Access 2007.
By deleting the key and everything under it, it fixes the cycling problem and Access 2007 opens right away.

Comment: can't get this to work.  It may be because I'm opening the same 2003 mdb file - sometimes with a 2003 shortcut, sometimes with a 2007 shortcut. Tried all the above but config continues to cycle.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by Windows Installer, which is used by both installers. Advertised shortcuts as used by both Office 2003 and Office 2007 invoke Windows Installer to check that the entire feature is installed properly; the installer detects that something else (in this case the other product) has registered the file extensions used by Access (possibly the ProgIds as well) and decides that a repair is necessary, so it invokes the 'Configuring Office' dialog and proceeds to reinstall various components.

To avoid this, run Access from Program Files directly; create shortcuts if you'll be doing this frequently.

Comment: Thanks for that Mike, but I am already using shortcuts with the program files specified. I think this trick used to work for Access 97/Access 2003 but it doesn't with 2007.

Comment: shortcuts to the EXEs don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Want to cut it down to about 20 seconds to reconfigure Access 2007 after opening Access 2003?  Download and install Office 2007 sp1:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9EC51594-992C-4165-A997-25DA01F388F5&displaylang=en

Btw, you can't avoid the reconfiguration between Access 2007 and earlier versions.  Access 2007 uses some of the same registry keys as earlier versions and they have to be rewritten when opening Access 2007.

Comment: After installing SP1 I tried opening Access 2003 and Access 2007 databases (with no code in them) and after several cycles the reconfiguration was taking:
  Access 2007: 32 sec
  Access 2003: 18sec

That's still quite slow but much better than 3 mins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I've found for this is to use VMWare Thinapp to virtualize one (or more) of the offending versions of Access:

http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/

It's a little more lightweight than a full Virtual PC / VMWare / etc installation, but unfortunately still a bit of a hassle to set up and not free.

Answer (score 0):

Just Install Office 2007 Sp2, that works.